# Counterexample: If $f: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \to \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is an isomorphism of fields, then $\beta=f(\alpha)$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

State whether the statement below is true or false:

If $f: \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \to \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ is an isomorphism of fields, then $\beta=f(\alpha)$.

If true, provide a proof; if false, provide a counter-example.

I know that this statement is false but I can't think of a counter-example.

Comment: What's $\beta$?  Did you mean to speak of an isomorphism $f:\mathbb Q(\alpha) \rightarrow \mathbb Q(\beta)$

Comment: What is $\beta$? Is $\alpha$ algebraic?

Comment: $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are not specified in this problem, and $f$ is an isomorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f the identity of Q=Q(1)=Q(-1), a counterexample

Comment: Ok to make sure. So when I proving that this is indeed a counterexample, I would do the following $$f(\alpha-1)=f(\alpha)-f(1)=\beta-1\neq \beta$$

Answer (score 1):

For an example where $Q(a)\ne Q$, let $a=\sqrt 2$ and $b= -a$. We have $Q(a)=Q(b)=\{x+y a :z,y\in Q\}$. Every $z\in Q(a)$ is equal to $x_z+y_z a$ where $x_z , y_z \in Q$ and are uniquely determined by $z$.  Let $f(x_z+y_za)=x_z-y_za$. This is a field isomorphism (a certain kind,called  an involution, because $f(f(z))=z)$.Observe that $f(a)=b\ne a$.